# (Phaser 3 Arcade) Issue with collisions between 2 circular bodies

Tags: typescript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I instantiate a bunch of extended Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite that move around the screen. When they hit each others, everything works has expected with the basic arcade body.

Although, It doesn't if I add "this.body.setCircle(200);" (or "this.setCircle(200);" btw, I'm not sure about the difference) in their constructor.
Instead of smoothly deflecting on impact as I would have hoped, they stop immediately.

Here's the code of my class:

```
import Phaser from "phaser";

export default class Sheep extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  target: Phaser.Math.Vector2 = new Phaser.Math.Vector2();
  speed: number = 50;
  reach: boolean = true;

  constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number, spriteKey: string) {
    super(scene, x, y, spriteKey);
    this.setOrigin(0, 0);
    scene.physics.add.existing(this);
    scene.add.existing(this);
    this.setCircle(5);
    this.visible = false;
    //this.scale = 0.05;
    //this.setBounce(1);
  }
  setRandomTarget() {
    this.target = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(
      Math.random() * this.scene.scale.width,
      Math.random() * this.scene.scale.height
    );
  }
  preUpdate(time: number, delta: number) {
    super.preUpdate(delta, time);
    if (
      this.reach ||
      this.target.distance(new Phaser.Math.Vector2(this.x, this.y)) <=
        this.speed
    ) {
      this.setRandomTarget();
      this.reach = false;
      this.setHeading();
    }
  }
  setHeading() {
    let vPos = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(this.x, this.y);
    let vTarget = this.target.clone();
    let velocity = vTarget.subtract(vPos).normalize().scale(this.speed);
    this.setVelocity(velocity.x, velocity.y);
  }
}
```

Here's the code to create them and add them to the scene:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.sheeps.push(
        new Sheep(
          this,
          Math.round(Math.random() * width),
          Math.round(Math.random() * height),
          "sheep2"
        )
      );
    }
    let sheepGroup = this.physics.add.group(this.sheeps);

    this.physics.add.collider(sheepGroup, sheepGroup);
```

Here's the result:
[Circular collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfG4p.jpg)
[Rectangular collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFTjW.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part one of your question**
If you extend from `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite` in the constructor you can do both, `this.setCircle` ([link documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setCircle__anchor)) or `this.body.setCircle` ([link documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html#setCircle__anchor)) should do the same thing.

**Part two of your question** *(look below for Update, solution)*
Why it doesn't work, is difficult to say, without seeing your code, but here is how I would diagnose the problem:

- turn on the debug setting for physics *(I assume the collision box is somehow offset)*

  ```
  var config = {
          ...
          physics: {
             default: 'arcade',
             arcade: {
                ...
                debug: true
             }
          },
    };
  ```
- check the browser console for errors *(immediate motion stop, indicates a probal error)*

**Update/Solution:**
After going over your code, I would have to say the problem is the line
`let sheepGroup = this.physics.add.group(this.sheeps);`

just change it to

`let sheepGroup = this.add.group(this.sheeps);`

and it should work. The physics of the phaser `group` is interfering with the physics bodies of the *sheeps*.

**Here the demo, I used for testing:**

```js
class Sheep extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {

  constructor(scene, x, y, spriteKey) {
    super(scene, x, y, spriteKey);
    this.target = new Phaser.Math.Vector2();
    this.speed = 50;
    this.reach = true;
    this.setOrigin(0, 0);
    scene.add.existing(this);
    scene.physics.add.existing(this);
    
    this.setCircle(5);
    this.visible = false;
    //this.scale = 0.05;
    this.setBounce(1);

  }
  setRandomTarget() {
    this.target = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(
      Math.random() * this.scene.scale.width,
      Math.random() * this.scene.scale.height
    );
  }
  preUpdate(time, delta) {
    super.preUpdate(delta, time);
    if (
      this.reach ||
      this.target.distance(new Phaser.Math.Vector2(this.x, this.y)) <=
        this.speed
    ) {
      this.setRandomTarget();
      this.reach = false;
      this.setHeading();
    }
  }

  setHeading() {
    let vPos = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(this.x, this.y);
    let vTarget = this.target.clone();
    let velocity = vTarget
        .subtract(vPos)
        .normalize()
        .scale(this.speed);

    this.setVelocity(velocity.x, velocity.y);
  }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: { create }
};

var controls;

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);


function create ()
{
    this.sheeps = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20
  ; i++) {
      this.sheeps.push(
        new Sheep(
          this,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 400),
          Math.round(Math.random() * 200),
          "sheep2"
        )
      );
    }
    let sheepGroup = this.add.group(this.sheeps);

    this.physics.add.collider(sheepGroup, sheepGroup);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added the sources and pictures of the outcome (don't hesitate to mention if some of this code seems odd, I'm new to Phaser 3/Typescript so, I'm probably not doing all this the "intended" way). I don't have any error/warning in the console.

Comment: @Bstrct thanks for the code helped find the problem, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also needed the this.setBounce(1); and everything works on my side as well.
To be clear, that is the right way to add a custom GameObject to the scene or am I doing it a weird way?
scene.physics.add.existing(this);
scene.add.existing(this);

Comment: @Bstrct I forgot to answer your comment. Well, yes I think, you are doing it right, there are serveral ways to do things in phaser, that is what makes it a bit confusing at times. _personally I would always attach the object first to the scene first and than to physics, but both should do the same thing. _(As far as I know)_